# Obtener el tamaño del elemento anterior

Tags: javascript

Como puedo obtener el ancho del anterior elemento, en mi caso de los elementos con la clase `d`, para así este `width` ***multiplicarlo por 2*** y aplicarselo al elemento con la clase como un ***marginTop***

Esto fué lo que intenté:

```js
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("d");
    var i=0,cl=c.length;
    for(;i<cl;i++) {
      if(c[i].previousElementSibling.innerHTML == undefined) continue;
      c[i].style.marginTop = c[i].previousElementSibling.clientWidth + "px";
      console.log(c[i].style.marginTop);
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
  .d {color:red;}
  
  </style>
  <p style="text-align:center">Emm titulo..</p>
  <b class="d">Holaa!</b>
  
</body>
</html>
```

***Pero no resulta en nada..***

Comment: ¿No sería **getElementsByClassName()**? Estas seleccionando todos los elementos con el tag **d** pero esos elementos no existen en tu documento....

Comment: Si javi, pero ese no es el error.. ya lo corregí en todo caso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes es correcto. El problema viene de otra parte: estás intentando aplicar un margen superior (`top-margin`) a un elemento `inline` (`b`). Por definición, los elementos en línea (*inline*) están dentro del flujo de la página y no se les puede aplicar un margen vertical (ni arriba ni abajo, pero sí a los lados).

Esto lo puedes encontrar en la [definición de `margin` por W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties%C2%B4) (traducción y énfasis míos):

> Las propiedades de margen especifican el ancho del márgen en la "caja". La propiedad corta 'margin' especifica el ancho para los cuatro lados, mientras que las otras propiedades sólo indican el margen para el lado respectivo. Estas propiedas aplican a todos los elementos, **pero los márgenes verticales no tendrán efecto en elementos en línea**.

Entonces para solucionar tu problema, lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar el elemento para que sea uno cuyo `display` no sea `inline` por defecto (por ejemplo, un `p` o un `div`). Otra opción sería especificar tu propio `display` con CSS:

```js
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("d");
var i = 0,
  cl = c.length;
for (; i < cl; i++) {
  if (c[i].previousElementSibling.innerHTML == undefined) continue;
  c[i].style.marginTop = c[i].previousElementSibling.clientWidth + "px";
  //console.log(c[i].style.marginTop);

}
```

```css
b { display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .d {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <p style="text-align:center">Emm titulo..</p>
  <b class="d">Holaa!</b>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiar :

```
c[i].previousElementSibling.getAttribute("width")
```

por :

```
c[i].previousElementSibling.clientWidth
```

o algo que te de verdaderamente el valor del "width" del elemento anterior pues con el ejemplo que pones arriba c[i].previousElementSibling.getAttribute("width") es null

Comment: lo edité pero sigue sin aplicar el margen